# VueJS not rendering data set inside for loop

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, scope, axios

I'm pretty new to VueJS so please bear with me! I'll try and explain in as much detail as possible.

So I'm creating a Vue app which will simply get a response from a sever, loop through the data and set a variable (Vue data) as the value.

However, when I Loop through the data in a for loop I can access and change The Vue data but it isn't rendered. See below for what I mean in more detail

My vue app:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            items: {}
        }
  },
    mounted() {
        //using Axios to post -> this all works
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'fetchOrder.php'
          //used both arrow and normal function still doesn't work
        }).then((response) => {
            response = Object.entries(response.data)
            for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
              //values are all correct
              this.items[response[i][0]] = response[i][1]
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I have been looking around everywhere and I can set this.items to the value of the response outside the for loop. however as soon as I put anything inside a for loop then due stops rendering the list (i'm rendering in cue simply using a v-for="order in order" which has been working).

Another thing which is very strange is that i'm using The Vue extension and the orders object has all the correct values so it is being set, the list just isn't rendered by VueJS. (See my vue plugin response below)

[Vue plugin data output - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4qmL.png)

So all I can think of is that its an issue with the scope and I can't use this. ? I have tried things like .bind(this) but that also didn't work.

Thanks for your time :)

**NOTE**: I'm not sure if this matters but I'm including Vue via CDN not the actual package

**NOTE**: The typo was just on stack overflow and did not fix my error

Comment: `items[response[i]0]` typo?

Comment: @JaromandaX yup this was a typo, just on stack overflow, hasn't fixed my issue - Good spot though!

Comment: it still looks all kinds of wrong `this.items[response[I][0]` - capital I, missing `]` - but I'll ignore that :p

Comment: thanks for that spot! I have corrected that now. however it hasn't fixed my issue

Comment: @J.Pegg42, might be occuring because of how Vue's reactivity works. Check this link
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: try using this.$set(this.items, response[i][0], response[i][1]). Instead of this.items[response[i][0]] = response[i][1].

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** using this.$set(this.items, response[i][0], response[I][1]) has fixed my issue.

Thanks @Hismanshu for this answer